# OAuth Confidential vs Public Client - What to choose if possible?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I understand the difference between Public and Confidential clients.

But what should be used if there is a choice?

Is Confidential Client preferable?

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends on your specific use case. Since you haven't specified it clearly, the thumb rule is we should aim for higher security. This in turn means opting for **Confidential client**.
Please visit this link to understand when Confidential or Public client should be used depending upon the various use cases.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications